# Fixing an element when it reaches the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have a script that fixes a `<header>` element after a certain amount of scrolling. How would I modify it so that the element scrolls normally until it gets to the top of the page *then* fixes. Something like [this](http://stanislav.it/tutorials/sticky-navigation/).

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Fix Sidebar 
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    sidebarHeight = $(".sidebar").height() + 70;
    console.log(sidebarHeight + ", " + windowHeight);
    if (windowHeight > sidebarHeight) {
        $('.sidebar').addClass("affix");
    }
});
```

N.B. `.affix` is just `{position:fixed}`.

### Site

The `<header>` element is the sidebar on the right with the big green demo button.

Comment: You got the plugin here for that: http://www.jozefbutko.com/stickyNavbar/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To make your sidebar fixed when the user scrolls down and reaches the top of the sidebar, use Jquery to add a class name to the sidebar when it reaches the window top position and add the `position:fixed` style to this new class.

```
var stickySidebar = $('.sidebar').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickySidebar) {
        $('.sidebar').addClass('affix');
    }
    else {
        $('.sidebar').removeClass('affix');
    }  
});
```

This will add a class name `affix` to the `sidebar` when the user scrolls down and reaches the top of the sidebar. Now add the fixed position to the `sidebar` with class name `affix`.

```
.sidebar.affix{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/WucN3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went with Matthew's plugin above in the end but this is a great snippet to keep hold of.

Comment: @Sebastian, just curious, if mine was the solution, why mark something that didn't solve your problem as the answer? :P

Comment: Because what I was looking for was a modification of the script I had rather than a plugin. Does that seem fair?

Comment: Most definitely. :) I was just curious. Thanks for the reply. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be looking for something like this: http://stickyjs.com/ (scroll to see it in action, you can do this to any element on a page). If that isn't what you are looking for let me know and I will help come up with something that suits your needs.

Comment: Wow, amazing plugin. Took 2 seconds and works perfectly.